# Return multiple functions in one endpoint - Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring app, and in my Services I have several functions :

```
public double[] CalculateStatistics();
public Double CalculateImprovement();
public int[] AverageAge();
public Double topScore();
```

And in the ServiceImpl, I have the calculations.
What I need is, to have an endpoint called /statistics.
And return everything that I'm calculating in these functions.
So then I can make an Ajax call to it and retrieve those data every few seconds if there is a change.

```
  @RequestMapping(value="statistics",method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

How do I do that ? Considering that some functions return an array, some a number. 
What is the best approach to use ? I'm only starting to learn Spring and Java, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Further to Bogdan's answer; the design pattern here is 'Data Transfer Object' or DTO (see wiki for further information).  I don't know about other developers, but I create a .dto package (i.e. separate from a model or domain package) to store these classes in.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object that will contain all necessary information.

```
@Data // Lombok annotation to generate all boilerplate code.
class Staticistic {
    private double[] statistics; // to store CalculateStatistics() result
    private double improvements; // to store CalculateImprovement() result
    private int[] averageAge;    // to store AverageAge() result
    private double topScore;     // to store topScore()
}

@RequestMapping(value="statistics",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Statistic> getStats() {
    ... your implementation ...
}
```

Also you can return a simple map and set all keys as you want. But preferable to create an object to store all this variables.

Comment: Thank you. But where do I create the object ? Where I have all my models? 
And then in the ResponseEntity I'd have :
Statistics.statistics = statisticsService.calculateStatistics() ?

Comment: @MonG, check [Spring guides](https://spring.io/guides). There are answers almost of all your questions about Spring project building. About statistic object: create it inside your method `getStats` for example